# Does SQL Azure support REPLACE T-SQL function with cyrillic characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database, management-studio-express

I am trying command like

```
USE [aaa]
GO
SELECT [Id]
      ,REPLACE([BlaBlaField], 'xyz','') 
  FROM [dbo].[aaa]
GO
```

through SQL Management Studio on SQL EXPRESS and SQL Azure Web Edition DB. In SQL Express it works, but on Azure it does not. I searched on the web at ['Azure SQL Database General Guidelines and Limitations'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx) page and on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx) page  but the command was not listed as not supported. Is it supported or not?

**UPDATE**
The problem appears only when I use cyrillic symbols. For example :

```
 USE [aaa]
    GO
    SELECT [Id]
          ,REPLACE([BlaBlaField], '2004','-') 
      FROM [dbo].[aaa]
    GO
```

works but :

```
 USE [aaa]
    GO
    SELECT [Id]
          ,REPLACE([BlaBlaField], '2004г','') 
      FROM [dbo].[aaa]
    GO
```

**UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED**

The problem was solved by not using REPLACE but a combination of [LEFT, RIGHT, SUBSTRING](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) avoiding the use or cyrillic characters.

does not.

Comment: FYI, it's not a command, it's a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replace function itself works in Azure SQL Database.

What does not work in SQL Database is USE [aaa]. You have to connect to the correct database first and then issues the statement in.

Comment: I have connected already and issued a simple SELECT which works as written above - with the USE command - it works in MSSQL Management Studio. The problem comes when I put REPLACE in order to select one column with part of the values modified.

Comment: Replace does work. In my case it does not work when I use cyrillic symbols inside the replace parameters.